# Adding custom maven project as dependency

Tags: java, maven, classpath, m2eclipse

I'm using eclipse with the m2eclipse plugin now I just want to resolve a - imho - easy problem: I've got two maven projects, I want to add `project A` as dependency to `project B`.

Well how do I achieve this in a manner way? If I add the `project A` to the build path of `project B` eclipse recognizes the classes but this project isn't resolved by eclipse on build time.

I got it working by installing `project A` to my local repo and adding this as dependency to my pom. This works but is cumbersome because I always have to install a new version of project A when something changed.

Shouldn't the plugin handle such a situation for me?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I tried it again but it fails that my workspace maven module cannot be resolved. The problem seems to be, that maven tries to resolve the dependency from my remote repositories - where project A isn't deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that you have both maven projects open in your workbench then make sure you have the "Enable Workspace Resolution" option enabled in the Maven context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Eclipse handle this situations.

You can add both the Projects A and B in the same work-space.

I could help you creating a simple work-space from the scratch.

I am assuming that you have already installed the MAVEN plugin [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) for Eclipse.

1. Start a new Eclipse in a blank Work-space
2. Right click on Project Explorer --> Go to Import dialog and add a Maven Module.
3. Locate the POM directory and add that directory.
4. It will list all the projects in all the sub folders.
5. Add as many as Maven Based modules in a single work-space.

By doing this you dont need to install the dependencies. Any change will be reflected on the derived module.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: can I do this something similar in intellij , currently I have to install the other project which is taking my time.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it is correct, because it assumes that project B will be using the dependency of project A that will be in the artifactory, so you can develop both independently.

And anyway, for the project A, if you are using maven, don't you use maven clean install for compiling and deploying? That way you are sure you always have the latest version

The other option is, in case both of the are more dependent of each other, you should consider make one of them as a module of the other, or maybe make a project C that contains both modules, but that would mean both of them are part of the same project (like an ear containing two jars), depends on the situation